# How would I store my search results into a table using a foreach loop in powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
Import-Module <JAMS>

$JAMSHistories = Get-JAMSHistory -Server TESTDUMMY2 -StartDate "01/20/2020" -EndDate "01/24/2020"

$historyTable = @()

foreach($JAMSHistory in $JAMSHistories)
{
    $row = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

    Write-Host $JAMSHistory.FinalSeverity
    if($JAMSHistory.FinalSeverity -match 'Success') 
    {
        $row | Add-Member -NotePropertyName JobSeveritySuccess ($JAMSHistory.FinalSeverity)
    }
    else {
        if ($JAMSHistory.FinalSeverity -match 'Error') {
            $row | Add-Member -NotePropertyName JobSeverityError ($JAMSHistory.FinalSeverity) }
    } $historyTable += $row 
} 

$historyTable
```

Comment: is there any error with the code you have here ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly are the properties of a `$JAMSHistory` object? What is the `Table` you want as result? (a [System.Data.DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8) or an array of PSObjects?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, which will output an array of objects (`$historyTable`) with a properties called `JobSeveritySuccess` and `JobSeverityError`.

```
$JAMSHistories = Get-JAMSHistory -Server TESTDUMMY2 -StartDate "01/20/2020" -EndDate "01/24/2020"

$historyTable = foreach ($JAMSHistory in $JAMSHistories) {

    $row = "" | Select JobSeveritySuccess,JobSeverityError
    if ($JAMSHistory.FinalSeverity -match 'Success') {
        $row.JobSeveritySuccess = $JAMSHistory.FinalSeverity
    }
    elseif ($JAMSHistory.FinalSeverity -match 'Error') {
        $row.JobSeverityError = $JAMSHistory.FinalSeverity
    }
    $row
}
# Output 
$historyTable
# Output in Table Format
$historyTable | Format-Table
```

The problem with this approach is that every object will have `JobSeveritySuccess` and `JobSeverityError` properties, and they may be empty. The only time both properties will have data is if `$JAMSHistory.FinalSeverity` contains `Error` and `Success` for the same object. There is probably a better way to do your design if provided more requirements.

---

When doing this type of exercise, there are always some gotchas. Consider creating a new `PSObject` or `PSCustomObject` for loop iteration. Then output that object at the end of the loop code. When collecting the `foreach` loop output, just set a variable equal to the `foreach` loop. There's rarely a need to use `+=` to build an array of `foreach` loop output. There could be some exceptions to this, but most of the time they are good things to consider.